# What have I encountered here?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, photography

Consider:

[image]

I tried [Google Lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Lens) to tell the answer, but it is not giving a true answer.

I am using the Android app *Stellarium*.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the name of the software you are using in your question?

Comment: Not enough for an answer but: [Google Sky Artifacts - Blue Donuts In Outer Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwkiqbJQvY)

Comment: it is an android app `stellarium` i thought so it would be app specific random image but i even search it on `worldwidetelescope.org` and found the same object at that constellation could you confirm it?please

Comment: It would be good if you can give your question a more descriptive title.

Comment: Spiderman. It's Spiderman.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are seeing is a result of internal reflections within the telescope that took the image used for plotting in the app you are using.

Here is a similar image (from [Google oops?](https://asterisk.apod.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12721))

[image]

Quoting from [Internal reflections](https://asterisk.apod.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12721#p87880) :

> The bluish features in both images are internal reflections in the
> telescope. When there is a very bright object in the field of view,
> the light can reflect around inside the telescope and camera before
> being recorded. The artifact is blue because both examples are from
> blue stars. There is probably a red artifact, too, but it is much
> fainter and more difficult to identify. Canis Major contains the
> brightest star in the sky, Sirius. Vega is somewhere near the top 10
> brightest stars. These are both likely to create reflection artifacts.
> The "spider" shaped shadow in the middle of the reflection is due to
> the secondary mirror of the telescope. The blue streaks near the top
> of the APOD image on November 30, 2005 are due to light leakage from
> sigma Orionis (one of the bright stars in the belt of Orion).

Additional details about this and other artifacts can be found in the YouTube video [Google Sky Artifacts - Blue Donuts In Outer Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwkiqbJQvY).